# omxplayer silent mode no-osd

Tags: omxplayer

sorry for the stupid question, I have to use Raspberry for a video installation but don't know a thing about. I do'nt want the osd, I read here that i have to write --no-osd somehow but I use Terminal on a mac, am connected to the Pi but nothing happens, I just have the menu show up… do I have to write something before that ? like sudo or something like taht (sorry I'm really a noob).
thanks if anyone can help

Comment: what is the command line you currently use - the general form of the command is `omxplayer [OPTIONS] [FILE]` ... you'd put `--no-osd` where the `[OPTIONS]` placeholder is - see `man omxplayer` for a full manual

Comment: HI, thanks for your explanation ! I did try this command but it has no effect. My file is called video.mp4 so I write " omxplayer --no-osd video.mp4"  But in return I have in my Terminal window just the technical information about the video not the disappearance of the on screen display.  Is it possible that my omxplayer has been modified and has a different name ?